# Imdb api with Ruby

Tags: ruby, api, imdb

I am trying to use the [imdb API](http://imdbapi.org/). I tried to search for Fargo, but when I run it, all I get is a black screen:

```
require 'net/http'

uri = URI.parse("http://imdbapi.org/")
response = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri, {"q" => "Fargo"})
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong or provide an example on how to retrieve the data from Fargo with a json in ruby from that api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple way:

```
require 'json'
require 'open-uri'
json = JSON.parse(open("http://imdbapi.org?q=Fargo") { |x| x.read }).first
```

To get individual element:

```
json['title'] 
#=> Fargo
```

Comment: this site is not working use this one instead, this is quite fast and seems to be free http://www.theimdbapi.org/

Answer (score 1):

This simple code below show us how to get a basic json data from imdb api:

```
require "net/http"
require "uri"

uri = URI.parse("http://imdbapi.org/?title=Fargo&type=json")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
response = http.request(request)

puts response.body
```

I use a verb GET in the REST way.

Comment: I get like: [{"runtime": ["98 min"], "rating":8.2, "genres" ... etc from the response.body
How do I get an individual element from this? example only the title

Comment: Updated my post for that. :)

Comment: In the same way like @kiddorails made it, 'json = JSON.parse(response.body).first', don't forget about to require 'json' .